# Igualar distancia puntos trayectoria

Tags: c#, unity

Dispongo de un array de vectores 3D (`Vector3[] pointsArray`) que representan la trayectoria curva de un elemento.

Sin embargo los diferentes puntos no siempre se encuentran a la misma distancia entre ellos.

¿Existe una forma de representar esta trayectoria con el mismo espaciado entre puntos (interpolando estos nuevos puntos) y conservando el primer y último punto?

La trayectoria es obtenida desde una fuente externa por lo que no  se puede hacer un preprocesado.

PD: Para los que no estén familiarizados con Unity, `Vector3` contiene las variables `x`, `y` y `z`.

Edit1:

La trayectoria es la de un proyectil pero con ciertos arreglos lo que significa que no siempre es una parábola perfecta.

Comment: Parece mas un tema matemático que de programación. Podrías dar un poco mas de información? La trayectoria es un circulo o cualquier curva? Puede cambiar de direccion? De donde vienen esos datos y porque los puntos estan a diferentes distancias unos de otros? Y porque los quieres a la misma distancia? Te pregunto esto ya que al interpolar los puntos sodría perderse información

Comment: La trayectoria es la de un proyectil pero tiene variaciones con cosas como podría ser el viento. Puede cambiar de dirección. Los puntos tienen diferentes distancias porque son capturados en diferente instante temporal. Los quiero a la misma distancia porque es más user friendly que el usuario lo vea así ya que los puntos de la trayectoria luego se dibujan. Entiendo que igual es más un tema matemático pero la respuesta que puedes obtener en este tipo de cuestiones en math overflow es prácticamente nula.

Comment: Aha, ahora entiendo la pregunta mejor :) Pero entiendes que al tener los puntos a intervalos regulares se podría perder algo de información no? Me refiero que al final sería una aproximación de la curva original

Comment: Ahora mismo ya se hace un procesado de la trayectoria usando el siguiente código: https://answers.unity.com/questions/392606/line-drawing-how-can-i-interpolate-between-points.html sin embargo pese a cambiar el smoothness y hacer que tenga en cuenta la distancia hay puntos de la trayectoria inicial que se encuentran demasiado cerca y genera aglomeraciones. Perder algún punto no supone un problema siempre que se acerque a la realidad y sea bonito de ver para el usuario.

Comment: Hmm. De todas maneras, una vez tienes la curva generada e interpolada para suavizarla...no puedes simplemente coger puntos a distancias similares que estén dentro de la curva que ya tienes? No te puedo especificar una implementación porque no soy ningun experto en matemáticas, pero por darte una idea...

Comment: Justo estaba pensando eso ahora mismo. Probablemente aumente el smoothness y haga un check de distancia para quedarme solo con las que me interesa si no encuentro otra solución. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: De nada. A ver si hay algun matemático por aqui de todas maneras que te pueda dar alguna fórmula mas exacta. Suerte :)